# three or more root in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
a = 3;
a = a^a // a = 27
</script>
```

is there something like that:

Comment: You mean [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation), not root.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Math.pow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp):

```
var a = 3;
a = Math.pow(a, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can pass '3^3' to a method if you like-

Math.toPow= function(s){
    s= s.split('^');
    return Math.pow(+s[0], +s[1]);
}

// or to validate input-

Math.toPow= function(s){
    s= s.split('^');
    try{
        return Math.pow(+s[0], +s[1]);
    }
    catch(er){
        return NaN;
    }
}

Math.toPow('3^3')

/*  returned value: (Number)
27
*/

// I prefer to use Math.pow(3,3)
Math.pow(3,3)

/*  returned value: (Number)
27
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

^ is called XOR.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: Unfortunately, mathematicians also use `x^y` as a shortform in ASCII text to mean x raised to the power of y. You need to understand the context to answer this question correctly since `3 XOR 3` does not equal 27.